# No property or field 'p' exists in type 'productByCategory'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, predicate, dynamic-linq

I am trying to create a dynamic query for filtering my data results. I am building a linqToSql query containing subqueries and filtering the result after that using
*System.Linq.Dynamic*. But my Approach is ending up in errors and i cant find a good amount of documentations over the library samples.

here is what i am trying to do. i am using a list to filter data by given filter ids, after i fetch the result with added sub query:

```
                List<long?> filter_list = new List<long?>();
                string query = "";
                if(mapped_filters!=null)
                    if (mapped_filters.Length > 0)
                    {
                        int i=0;
                        foreach (string item in mapped_filters)
                        {
                            long filter = 0;
                            long.TryParse(item, out filter);                                
                            filter_list.Add(filter);
                            query += " p.prod_attrs.Contains(@"+i+") ||";
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                query = query.TrimEnd(new char []{ '|','|'});
```

and following is the code for linq fetch on my products:

```
                var productByCategory = db.products.Where(p => p.is_active == true && p.mainCat_id == cat_id).
                        Select(p => new productByCategory
                        {
                            id = p.id ,
                            prod_name = p.product_name,
                            prod_price = db.product_pricings.Where(pr => pr.prod_id == p.id  && pr.currency_id == 2).FirstOrDefault(),
                            //filters below
                            prod_attrs = db.prod_attr_maps.Where(pa => pa.prod_id == p.id  && pa.is_active == true 
                                && pa.currency_id == 2)
                            .Select(pa => pa.attr_id).ToList()                                
                        }).Where(p =>
                            (p.prod_price.our_price + p.prod_price.shipping_cost) >= min &&
                            (p.prod_price.our_price + p.prod_price.shipping_cost) <= max)
                            .Where("p=>"+query,filter_list)
                        .OrderBy(p => p.newItem).ToList();
```

but this ends up in error :

> No property or field 'p' exists in type 'productByCategory'
>   ..... Parse Exception

So far i have tried replacing

> .Where("p=>"+query,filter_list)

To

> .Where(""+query,filter_list)

and query part to

> query += " prod_attrs.Contains(@"+i+") ||";

but still same error p replaced by prod_attrs exception.

**EDIT**

i did some direct string placement in the query and it seems like a problem with dynamic linq dll, when i do query like this :

> *.Where("id==1 && prod_name.Contains(\"a\")")* it works fine

but with

> *.Where("id==1 && prod_name.Contains(1)")*

it ends up in error :

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No generic method 'Contains' on type
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type
>   arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the
>   method is non-generic.

So it clearly seems to be a functionality issue with dynamic linq library.

Comment: What does the value of `query` look like after you generate the dynamic query?

Comment: p=>p.prod_attrs.contains(1) || p.prod_attrs.contains(2) ...... like this it evaluates for the filter ids

Comment: Use `prod_attrs` directly so that the query would become like this: `prod_attrs.contains(1) || prod_attrs.contains(2)`

Comment: tried that also , please read last of my question still getting exception

Comment: Can you show the value of `query` after such change?

Comment: it is as you posted prod_attrs.contains(1) || prod_attrs.contains(2)

Comment: does this have something to do with subquery list ??     
prod_attrs = db.prod_attr_maps.Where(pa => pa.prod_id == p.id  && pa.is_active == true 
                                && pa.currency_id == 2)
                            .Select(pa => pa.attr_id).ToList()

Comment: What happens if you replace the dynamic query with a normal one just for the sake of testing?

Comment: for single filter i get right result if i replace the part .Where("p=>"+query,filter_list) with .Where(p=>p.prod_attrs.Contains(1)) it works and give only those results with filter id 1 in them

Comment: I'd start by replacing the `p` in `Select(p => new productByCategory` with another variable. It could be getting confused with the `p` in your select statement.

Comment: k will try and let you know first thing in morning....

Comment: " p.prod_attrs.Contains(@" must be " it.prod_attrs.Contains(@".

Comment: same result : *An exception of type 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException' occurred in System.Linq.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No property or field 't' exists in type 'productByCategory'*

Comment: i did some direct string placement in the query and it seems like a problem with dynamic linq dll, when i do query like this : *.Where("id==1 && prod_name.Contains(\"a\")")* it works fine but with *.Where("id==1 && prod_name.Contains(1)")*  it ends up in error : **An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No generic method 'Contains' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.**

Comment: what type for `prod_name`? if this list of string, so you can't call `Contains` with int parameter

Comment: its of long? list type, i have already checked for all type safes